create graphs in google sheets based on date with aggregates
I'm sure this is simple enough to do for those familiar with sheets. I have a data set that could have 0 to many entries per day sorted in descending order currently. Like this:

I want a line graph and a bar graph that represent similar information.
The line graph I'd like to grow continually up representing count of the total entries at that point in time. So for 4/30 value would be 2. 5/1 would be 3, 5/7 would be 6, etc etc.
The bar graph i'd like a count of entries by month. so in this case 4/2024 would be 2 and 5/2024 would be 9.

for line chart:
=QUERY(QUERY(QUERY(A2:A, "select todate(A)", ), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1"), 
 "offset 1", )



for bar chart:
=INDEX(QUERY(QUERY(TEXT(FILTER(A2:A, A2:A<>""), "mmm e"), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) group by Col1"), 
 "offset 1", ))


